# How do I make my discord bot send this message to a specific channel?

Tags: python, discord

Here is my code, I need it to send the response to a specific channel. Can't seem to find how to do it anywhere in the API.

```
@bot.tree.command(name='training', description='Set up a training date & announce it to everyone in the server')

@app_commands.describe(date = "Date")
@app_commands.describe(time = "Time")
@app_commands.describe(location = "Location")

async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, date: str, time: str, location: str):
  await interaction.response.send_message(f"{interaction.user.mention} is training at {location} on {date} at {time}")
```

I've tried changing the "interaction.response.send_message" into "channel.send" but that gave back an error with the atr: send

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the channel ID somewhere - and then fetch that channel object when the interaction is invoked and *then* send the message.

The docs:

- [Interaction object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interaction)
- [Guild object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild)
- [Channel object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel)
- [interaction response object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse)

````py
MY_CHANNEL_ID = 123455678

@bot.tree.command(name='training', description='Set up a training date & announce it to everyone in the server')
@app_commands.describe(date = "Date")
@app_commands.describe(time = "Time")
@app_commands.describe(location = "Location")

async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, date: str, time: str, location: str):
    my_channel = await interaction.guild.fetch_channel(MY_CHANNEL_ID)
    # could also do it this way if the command can be used outside a guild context
    # my_channel = await bot.fetch_channel(MY_CHANNEL_ID)

    await my_channel.send(f"{interaction.user.mention} is training at {location} on {date} at {time}")```

    # make sure we notify the user that we did what they wanted to do and respond
    await interaction.response.send_message("Done the thing", ephemeral=True)
````

To get the Channel ID follow [this guide](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-) and right-click on the channel you want to send the message to.

Comment: This did it! thank you so much for your help and for the supporting docs attached!

Comment: No worries! Happy to help. Remember to mark the answer as answered when you can!